# What is the best way to re-use conditional logic in a Rails 4 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My goal is to display a user's profile image. Some users will not have uploaded profile images, so I'd like to display a default profile image for them.

I can do this in the view like this:

```
    <% if post.user.avatar.presence %>
    <%= image_tag post.user.avatar.url %>
    <% else %>
    <%= link_to user_path(post.user), :class => "default-profile-image" do %>
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

But this seems sub-optimal. What if I want to use the logic elsewhere? I don't want to repeat this code in my views.

What is the optimal way to recycle this code elsewhere in my app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

You should create an `app/views/users/_avatar.html.erb` partial, move the code in your question there, and then each time you want to render an avatar, use

```
<%= render 'users/avatar', user: post.user %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using CarrierWave or PaperClip, these libraries have default/fallback images. For [fallback images in CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url), you'd just define the `default_url` method on the uploader associated with your User's profile images.

This doesn't achieve the HTML as you have in your code, but I assume it could replace that. If you really want the HTML as shown in your code, I'd recommend using a [Presenter](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-presenters/) that wraps your User object which would output the proper HTML if the avatar isn't present, perhaps by rendering a partial, as suggested by @meagar. My point here is: try to accomplish your goals just by calling methods on objects. There should generally be a simple-enough way to call a method on the object in question and have it output what you need.